# Increasing number of flags

Tags: feature-request, flagging

Would it be possible to keep the same formula that gives more flags before 500 and just carry it forward?

I don't think that anyone on SU will hit 100 flags (the current ceiling I think).

**EDIT:** See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82308/why-did-my-number-of-remaining-inform-moderator-flags-go-up) for more details on the current system.

Comment: We have one user with the [Marshal](http://superuser.com/badges/121/marshall) badge already, and I suspect others will be there soon.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a good idea.  What if a new user doesn't flag for a month?  Then he has collected a ton of flags that he hasn't used, and therefore can flood the mods with flags that may or may not be valid.  Flagging is a privilege that will be rewarded for good behavior. I feel it needs to stay that way.

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear. I am not talking about adding cumalative flags, just increasing the flag count in the same way that it is done before 500 after 500 as well.

Comment: @sandos... I'm not sure I understand... you want more flags after 500?

Comment: Yes, on the same basis that more flags are given before 500.

Comment: This confuses me even more then:

>I don't think that anyone on SU will hit 100 flags<  leads me to believe that 100 is too much...

Comment: max flag weight will be 10+(750-100)/20+rep/2k. For John T (assuming he has 750 flag weight) it would give 79 flags.

Comment: If you're using 100 flags though, I feel that there might be an issue with how you're using them.

Comment: But you won't be getting 100... The highest person might have up to 79... And currently, I believe Jon Skeet would have 100 flags now (On SO).

Comment: so what's the base complaint?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think that anyone on SU will hit 100 flags (the current ceiling I think).

So you're asking for a feature you admit is unlikely to ever benefit *anyone*?

Um... Why?

Comment: No, everyone above 500 flag weight will get more flags, but not 100... I get the feeling that that line is more trouble than it is worth...