# What is the difference: [flag] and [flagging]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Here in Meta Super User, we have [flag](/questions/tagged/flag) and [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging)

[flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging) has more questions that [flag](/questions/tagged/flag).

What is the difference? Are these tags synonymic? If yes, which one should we keep?

Comment: To me, the flagging tag sounds more natural. That's my own opinion though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Make [flag](/questions/tagged/flag) a synonym of [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging)

I've reviewed the questions asked in these two tags (including four that [used both tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/flagging+flag)) and see no material difference between them.  The end objective is the same: To ask about flags, how to flag, when to flag, how flags work, and [why my flag was declined](https://meta.superuser.com/q/10886/213131).

I find it interesting these two tags have questions dating back to [2010](https://meta.superuser.com/q/1724/213131) and [2011](https://meta.superuser.com/q/3238/213131) respectively and to my knowledge this is the first time anyone's noticed the possible tag duplication.

that said, now might be a good time for someone to update the tag [wiki](https://meta.superuser.com/edit-tag-wiki/195).

Comment: I've merged flags into flagging, made flag a synonym, and created a tag summary for flagging. The tag description still needs to be added. Feel free to edit :)